# How can I rebroadcast an RTSP stream and support pause, speed adjustment, and rewind?

Tags: video, video-streaming, rtsp

I have a very bare-bones RTSP stream I'm trying to rebroadcast for a robust client to then watch with controls such as pause and rewind.

According to the [RTSP RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt) features such as PAUSE and SET_PARAMETER (for playback speed) are optional in the protocol. Difficulty finding a server supporting these features aside, I don't feel clear whether rewind support is theoretically possible, and if so how it is controlled; at least, it doesn't seem as though it is a typical RTSP feature on either client or server, yet there also does not appear to be a standard more-robust protocol used for RTSP rebroadcast playback.

It's difficult to articulate this problem without making it purely opinionated, but after some unfruitful research, I am looking to understand what sane options there are for more robust RTSP / other streaming playback, and I would really appreciate any insight advanced streamers have on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may help to take a step back and look at what RTSP is and how it relates to your video streams.

RTSP itself is a streaming control protocol, to control streaming servers.

It has been compared to a 'TV remote control' like protocol - i.e. it provides the means to start, stop, rewind, fast forward etc a streaming server.

RSTP does not actually transport the media data itself - in most RSTP use cases, RTP (Real Time Transport) protocol takes care of this.

So, in much the same way your TV remote control can pause, fast forward, rewind etc some streams (VOD streams, catchup, recording etc) but can't do the same for others streams (Live TV which has no catchup enabled for example), similarly RTSP capability is restricted by the nature of the steam itself.

For example, if your RTSP stream is from a live security or web camera, you clearly won't be able to fast forward from the live stream, and you generally won't be able to rewind either unless the source supports this functionality.

For your use case it may be easiest to stream the RTSP to a video streaming server, which can then store and restream the video to multiple clients. This will allow you implement storage and catchup, with rewind etc, on the video server. You could also convert to HLS and DASH which will likely give you much better playback support across browsers and apps, at the cost of latency in the stream, if that is acceptable for your use case.